# Does diagnolizing higher-order cross-moment matrices lead to independent variables?

Tags: self-study, multivariate-analysis, independence, method-of-moments, generalized-moments

Diagonalizing the covariance matrix transforms multivariate data into uncorrelated variables, but does not make them independent necessarily. Does it follow from this that if I were to diagonalize every cross-moment matrix (e.g. cokurtosis, coskewness), then I can obtain independent variables in general?

Ignoring the difficulties of estimating higher order cross-moments, does this thought process make sense? (Is it not possible to diagonalize each cross-moment matrix at once?)

Also, how gross of assumption is it that only the first $N$ moments are relevant in describing a set of observations? (Kind of like how power spectra of real signal fizzles off at higher frequencies)

Comment: Please explain what you mean by a "higher order cross-moment matrix." Most moments cannot be placed naturally into (two dimensional) matrices. For instance, the third central moments of a vector-valued random variable $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ with mean $(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n)$ are of the form $\mathbb{E}((X_i-\mu_i)^3)$, $\mathbb{E}((X_i-\mu_i)^2(X_j-\mu_j))$ (for $i\ne j$) and $\mathbb{E}((X_i-\mu_i)(X_j-\mu_j)(X_k-\mu_k))$ (for $i\ne j\ne k$). Exactly how would you arrange those into a matrix?

Comment: Is it important that higher order cross-moments are represented as two dimensional matrices? If they can be diagonalized in the form they are naturally in, then it seems valid. For example, the third central moment 3D matrix, the only non-zero elements lie where $i = j = k$ would be the equivalent diagonalization. (Although, I'm not sure how easy this is or if it is even possible)